# Haversine is not giving me correct result

Tags: ruby, haversine

I am trying to calculate distance between two points in kilometers but it is giving me wrong.

```
location.each do |loc|
  distance =  Haversine.distance(28.6139, 77.209, loc[:lat].to_f, loc[:long].to_f).to_km           
puts "  #{distance}"
end
```

Here is the distance which I am getting and which is wrong

```
 7385.99072855455
 7383.795725224046
7392.13122601482
 7391.537885880786
```

The data of the location is in my database

```
[{"id":1,"lat":28.6139,"lng":77.209,"location":"","object_id":1,"created_at":"2016-06-07T05:46:53.000Z","updated_at":"2016-06-07T05:46:53.000Z","object_type":"abc"},{"id":2,"lat":28.6692,"lng":77.4538,"location":"","object_id":2,"created_at":"2016-06-07T05:49:23.000Z","updated_at":"2016-06-07T05:49:23.000Z","object_type":"cde"},{"id":3,"lat":28.4595,"lng":77.0266,"location":"","object_id":3,"created_at":"2016-06-07T05:50:22.000Z","updated_at":"2016-06-07T05:50:22.000Z","object_type":"ggg"},{"id":4,"lat":28.4744,"lng":77.504,"location":"","object_id":4,"created_at":"2016-06-07T05:50:24.000Z","updated_at":"2016-06-07T05:50:24.000Z","object_type":"eerr"}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? How much off is it? Perhaps remove "sssssss" before posting here?

Comment: yeah i have remove sss and it should be withing 50 km or less than that

Comment: What is `loc`? Does it really have symbols as keys?

Comment: loc is basically for looping from location table.I have also provided data from my location table which is been save in my database

Comment: Instead `something.to_f`, use `Float(something)`. `to_f` silently ignores exceptions.

Comment: I know what `loc` is __for__, but I don't know what it __is__.

Comment: Loc is a local variable for looping all the record present inside the location table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: `loc[:long]` instead of `loc[:lng]`, the line should read:

```
Haversine.distance(28.6139, 77.209, loc[:lat].to_f, loc[:lng].to_f).to_km
```

You passed `nil.to_f` as _longitude of the second point. This is equivalent to passing `0`